# SwiftUI List Item decoration affects slide to delete

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list that has items like this:

```
 List {
  ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
     Text(item.termLowerCase)
  .font(fontItems)
  .foregroundColor(.white)
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  .contentShape(Rectangle())
  .onTapGesture {
     // doSomething()
  }
  .onDelete { offsets in
   print("deleting"
  }
  .listRowBackground(
    Group {
      if item == selectedItem {
        Color("selectedColor").mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
      } else {
        Color.clear
      }
    }
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 5, bottom: 0, trailing: 5))
  )
```

This code produces elements like the ones below, including the rounded corner of the selected element.

[image]

My problem is that this cell decoration prevents the slide cell to left to delete to work

How do I solve that?

1. I want the whole cell, from left to right, tappable, not just the words.
2. I want slide to left to work.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue, but I had to modify it so it would compile. The code formatting is bad, missing brackets, and you don't show how variables are declared at the top of the View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be attached `.onDelete` in wrong place, it should be attached to `ForEach` (not inside for row)

```
  ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
     Text(item.termLowerCase)
  }
  .onDelete { offsets in    // << here !!
    print("deleting"
  }
```

Comment: Would you provide complete reproducible example to debug?

Comment: Your answer is technically right because the code I have posted was incorrect. But my problem was outside this scope, on another class. Anyway, thanks.